# Heroku Were sorry but something went wrong

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was trying to enter another page on my app from heroku, but I can't because it says "We're sorry but something went wrong.

here is something from my heroku log

```
2014-02-13T18:58:20.617640+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=whispering-shore-8429.herokuapp.com request_id=0ea
ebe7-bea5-417b-b371-462a071c2f45 fwd="68.55.131.71" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=229ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-13T18:58:20.762361+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/assets/application-ec238357b2bb2d82a5fd2c7675f7d5ea.css
ost=whispering-shore-8429.herokuapp.com request_id=4de97dca-391d-4181-a4fa-f2c0fdeb2203 fwd="68.55.131.71" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms
ervice=9ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-13T19:02:22.251866+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/live_players" for 68.55.131.71 at 2014-02-13 19:02:22 +0000
2014-02-13T19:02:22.253790+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LivePlayersController#index as HTML
2014-02-13T19:02:22.251866+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/live_players" for 68.55.131.71 at 2014-02-13 19:02:22 +0000
2014-02-13T19:02:22.253790+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LivePlayersController#index as HTML
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                    ^
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
2014-02-13T19:02:26.453212+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered live_players/index.html.erb within layouts/application (18.3ms)
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
2014-02-13T19:02:26.453456+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4200ms
2014-02-13T19:02:26.453456+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4200ms
2014-02-13T19:02:26.453212+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered live_players/index.html.erb within layouts/application (18.3ms)
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                    ^
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                    ^
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:    <% end %>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:            <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: </select>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team):
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/live_players/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_live_players_index_html_erb_
_2359354532860974770_70257406404860'
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: <select id = "FilterTm">
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455611+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:            <option>Select a Team...</option>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                    ^
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: <select id = "FilterTm">
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:    <% end %>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: </select>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/live_players/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_live_players_index_html_erb_
_2359354532860974770_70257406404860'
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455800+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team):
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:            <option>Select a Team...</option>
2014-02-13T19:02:26.455976+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:            <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
```

Now i noticed that is says column 'team' does not exists, but that is not true. Here is my page:

```
<h1>Listing All Players</h1>

<div id="progressbar"><div class="progress-label">Loading...</div></div>

<a id="playerBtn"><button type="button" id="plyrBtn">Players</button></a>

<select id = "FilterTm">
    <option>Select a Team...</option>
<% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
    <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
<% end %>
</select>

<%#= link_to '<button type = "button">Players</button>'.html_safe, live_players_path(:Team => @tmf) %>


<br />


<br />
<input type="text" class="hiddenField" id="curTeam" style="border:none;" />

<select id = "ptable" size = 30>
<% @live_players.each do |live_player| %>
    <option><%= live_player.Plyr %></option>
<% end %>
</select>
```

which is the page it's trying to get. Now here is my routes file:

```
TestfflApp::Application.routes.draw do

root "static_pages#home"

get "static_pages/Add_team"

resources :teamplayers

resources :fteams

resources :abbrvs

resources :live_players

get 'live_players', to: 'live_players#index' << Routed page
```

So i have looked on here and done all of the suggestions for questions similiar to this, so what problem am I having?

**Update**

Here is what the heroku log says now:

```
`2014-02-13T20:37:48.237162+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
2014-02-13T20:37:56.719387+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LivePlayersController#index as HTML
2014-02-13T20:37:56.717608+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/live_players" for 68.55.131.71 at 2014-02-13 20:37:56 +0000
2014-02-13T20:37:56.717608+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/live_players" for 68.55.131.71 at 2014-02-13 20:37:56 +0000
2014-02-13T20:37:56.719387+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by LivePlayersController#index as HTML
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-02-13T20:38:00.091753+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered live_players/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
2014-02-13T20:38:00.092187+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3373ms
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team):
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.089740+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: <select id = "FilterTm">
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:            <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:    <% end %>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: </select>
  2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error:  FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:            <option>Select a Team...</option>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/live_players/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_live_players_index_html_erb__
2392315387062206729_69827916979320'
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.091873+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered live_players/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4.7ms)
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team):
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:      7: <select id = "FilterTm">
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:      8:            <option>Select a Team...</option>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:      9:    <% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:     10:            <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:     11:    <% end %>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096859+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.092187+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3373ms
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/views/live_players/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_live_players_index_html_erb__
2392315387062206729_69827916979320'
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-02-13T20:38:00.097200+00:00 app[web.1]:     12: </select>
2014-02-13T20:38:00.096530+00:00 app[web.1]:      6:
2014-02-13T20:37:47.810030+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=whispering-shore-8429.herokuapp.com request_id=a91b
2a9e-24c1-4481-a973-e6385393035f fwd="68.55.131.71" dyno=web.1 connect=30ms service=113ms status=304 bytes=0
2014-02-13T20:38:00.106578+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/live_players host=whispering-shore-8429.herokuapp.com request_id=a8c5e9d7-bac5-4058-87d0-497330b5c4dd fwd="68.55.131.71" dyno=web.1 connect=6ms service=3399ms status=500 bytes=1266`
```

Comment: Can you post a list of your models and their attributes?

Answer (score 0):

This is your error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist...
```

My guess is you updated your database with a migration, but didn't do it on Heroku. Just run the following from your console.

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

That should fix your error.

Comment: ok that fixed that error but there is a new one now it is in the update on my post

Comment: This message indicates a backend connection was terminated. This can happen when a user issues pg:kill from the command line client, or similarly runs SELECT pg_cancel_backend(pid); from a psql session.  Did you run the migrations and wait till they were finished?

Comment: Right, then what happened?  Did the migrations run without error?  Are you able to access your app on Heroku? Does a page refresh work?  Is someone else issuing database commands?

Comment: yes it ran without error, Yes i can access the app, but only the home page with is a static page. page refresh only works on the home page. no one is issuing commands

Comment: And every time you go to another page do your logs still show the same error?  I ask because usually that error on Heroku is caused by maintenance.

Comment: hmmm good point it looks like only pages that have rails tags in it that have table queries in them. like above. it looks like the page is having a problem with this code: `<select id = "FilterTm">
    <option>Select a Team...</option>
    <% Abbrv.order("Team").each do |abbrv| %>
    <option><%= abbrv.Team %></option>
<% end %>
</select>` which is displayed in the first log from my post. I mean it should not return anything but instead it does not load the page

Comment: Is there an error associated with that?  Does your code work locally?

Comment: locally everything works, the error associated with that is: `2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                    ^
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team
2014-02-13T19:02:26.441393+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT "abbrvs".* FROM "abbrvs"   ORDER BY Team`

Comment: maybe there is a way for me to upload my heroku logs somewhere for you to see it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47522/discussion-between-chrisbarthol-and-user3240928)